# Moving a &[&str] into a thread

Tags: rust

As the title already says, I'm trying to move a `&[&str]` into a thread. Well, actually, the code below works, but I have two problems with it:

1. `let args2: Vec<_> = args.iter().map(|arg| { arg.to_string() }).collect();` seems a bit verbose to convert a `&[&str]` into a `Vec<String>`. Can this be done "nicer"?
2. If I understand it correctly, the strings get copied twice: first by the `let cmd2` and `let args2` statements; then by moving them inside the `move` closure. Is this correct? And if so, can it be done with one copy?

I'm aware of `thread::scoped`, but is deprecated at the moment. I'm also coding this to learn a bit more about Rust, so comments about "unrusty" code are appreciated too.

```
use std::process::{Command,Output};
use std::thread;
use std::thread::JoinHandle;

pub struct Process {
    joiner: JoinHandle<Output>,
}

impl Process {
    pub fn new(cmd: &str, args: &[&str]) -> Process {
        // Copy the strings for the thread
        let cmd2 = cmd.to_string();
        let args2: Vec<_> = args.iter().map(|arg| { arg.to_string() }).collect();

        let child = thread::spawn(move || {
            Command::new(cmd2).args(&args2[..]).output().unwrap_or_else(|e| {
                panic!("Failed to execute process: {}", e)
            })
        });
        Process { joiner: child }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `let args2: Vec<_> = args.iter().map(|arg| { arg.to_string() }).collect();` seems a bit verbose to convert a &[&str] into a Vec. Can this be done "nicer"?

I don't think so. There are a few minor variations of this that also work (e.g. `args.iter().cloned().map(String::from).collect();`), but I can't think of one that is substantially nicer. One minor point is that using `to_string` to convert a `&str` to a `String` isn't quite as efficient as using `String::from` or `to_owned`.

> If I understand it correctly, the strings get copied twice: first by the let cmd2 and let args2 statements; then by moving them inside the move closure. Is this correct? And if so, can it be done with one copy?

No, the strings are only copied where you call `to_string`. Strings don't implement `Copy`, so they're never copied implicitly. If you try to access the strings after they have been moved to the closure, you will get a compiler error.

Comment: Thank you for `String::from`. For the second point, I first explicitly copy the strings into `cmd2` and `args2`, but when they are moved into the closure, aren't they physically copied on the thread's stack too?

Comment: @Garogolun Well, the vector is copied, but that is only a shallow copy (i.e. the struct containing a pointer, length and capacity). The content of the vector isn't copied.

Comment: The thread can access the content of the vector. However, if `Process::new` returns, the vector along with its content gets destructed. Wouldn't this be unsafe then?

Comment: @Garogolun No, the vector's content will not be destroyed at the end of `Process::new` because the vector has been moved into the closure, which means cleaning up the vector has become the closure's responsibility.

Comment: Ah, apparently I incorrectly assumed that the vector's content resides in the stack as well. Thank you!